# Is there a penalty for using static variables in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, static

In C++11, this:

```
const std::vector<int>& f() {
    static const std::vector<int> x { 1, 2, 3 };
    return x;
}
```

is thread-safe. However, is there an extra penalty for calling this function after the first time (i.e. when it is initialized) due to this extra thread-safe guarantee? I am wondering if the function will be slower than one using a global variable, because it has to acquire a mutex to check whether it's being initialized by another thread every time it is called, or something.

Comment: What makes you think this is thread safe?

Comment: @ZacHowland: The standard guarantees that the initialization is thread-safe and that there be no deadlocks. (says nothing about accessing, luckily...)

Comment: @Damon I get that ... but his question is implying there is a hidden mutex, which there is not.  The only check that would happen here is to see if the vector has been initialized.

Comment: [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f79912e741d1bb23) the asm from your code (I got rid of initial values to simplify). Note the calls to `__cxa_guard_acquire` and `__cxa_guard_release`. Now compile the same code with `-fno-threadsafe-statics` and those calls will be gone.

Comment: @ZacHowland:  ... which needs some form of being threadsafe too, such as using an atomic fetch. Otherwise, there'd be the possibility of initializing the variable twice.

Comment: -fno-threadsafe-statics is a blessing, but unluckily it's breaking the standard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

["The best intution to be ever had is 'I should measure this.'"](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920) So [let's find out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0337d476ab35478c):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

namespace {
class timer {
    using hrc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    hrc::time_point start;

    static hrc::time_point now() {
      // Prevent memory operations from reordering across the
      // time measurement. This is likely overkill, needs more
      // research to determine the correct fencing.
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      auto t = hrc::now();
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      return t;
    }

public:
    timer() : start(now()) {}

    hrc::duration elapsed() const {
      return now() - start;
    }

    template <typename Duration>
    typename Duration::rep elapsed() const {
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(elapsed()).count();
    }

    template <typename Rep, typename Period>
    Rep elapsed() const {
      return elapsed<std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>>();
    }
};

const std::vector<int>& f() {
    static const auto x = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
    return x;
}

static const auto y = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
const std::vector<int>& g() {
    return y;
}

const unsigned long long n_iterations = 500000000;

template <typename F>
void test_one(const char* name, F f) {
  f(); // First call outside the timer.

  using value_type = typename std::decay<decltype(f()[0])>::type;
  std::cout << name << ": " << std::flush;

  auto t = timer{};
  auto sum = uint64_t{};
  for (auto i = n_iterations; i > 0; --i) {
    const auto& vec = f();
    sum += std::accumulate(begin(vec), end(vec), value_type{});
  }
  const auto elapsed = t.elapsed<std::chrono::milliseconds>();
  std::cout << elapsed << " ms (" << sum << ")\n";
}
} // anonymous namespace

int main() {
  test_one("local static", f);
  test_one("global static", g);
}
```

Running at Coliru, the local version does 5e8 iterations in 4618 ms, the global version in 4392 ms. So yes, the local version is slower by approximately 0.452 nanoseconds per iteration. Although there's a measurable difference, it's too small to impact observed performance in most situations.

---

EDIT: Interesting counterpoint, [switching from clang++ to g++ changes the result ordering](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a97f245775b8ed1). The g++-compiled binary runs in 4418 ms (global) vs. 4181 ms (local) so *local* is faster by 474 picoseconds per iteration. It does nonetheless reaffirm the conclusion that the variance between the two methods is small.

---

EDIT 2: Examining the generated assembly, I decided to convert from function pointers to function objects for better inlining. Timing with indirect calls through function pointers isn't really characteristic of the code in the OP. So I used this program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

namespace {
class timer {
    using hrc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    hrc::time_point start;

    static hrc::time_point now() {
      // Prevent memory operations from reordering across the
      // time measurement. This is likely overkill.
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      auto t = hrc::now();
      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      return t;
    }

public:
    timer() : start(now()) {}

    hrc::duration elapsed() const {
      return now() - start;
    }

    template <typename Duration>
    typename Duration::rep elapsed() const {
      return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(elapsed()).count();
    }

    template <typename Rep, typename Period>
    Rep elapsed() const {
      return elapsed<std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>>();
    }
};

class f {
public:
    const std::vector<int>& operator()() {
        static const auto x = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
        return x;
    }
};

class g {
    static const std::vector<int> x;
public:
    const std::vector<int>& operator()() {
        return x;
    }
};

const std::vector<int> g::x{ 1, 2, 3 };

const unsigned long long n_iterations = 500000000;

template <typename F>
void test_one(const char* name, F f) {
  f(); // First call outside the timer.

  using value_type = typename std::decay<decltype(f()[0])>::type;
  std::cout << name << ": " << std::flush;

  auto t = timer{};
  auto sum = uint64_t{};
  for (auto i = n_iterations; i > 0; --i) {
    const auto& vec = f();
    sum += std::accumulate(begin(vec), end(vec), value_type{});
  }
  const auto elapsed = t.elapsed<std::chrono::milliseconds>();
  std::cout << elapsed << " ms (" << sum << ")\n";
}
} // anonymous namespace

int main() {
  test_one("local static", f());
  test_one("global static", g());
}
```

Not surprisingly, runtimes were faster under both [g++ (3803ms local, 2323ms global)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8c6717433db3387) and [clang (4183ms local, 3253ms global)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/072061908c978a7e). The results affirm our intuition that the global technique should be faster than the local, with deltas of 2.96 nanoseconds (g++) and 1.86 nanoseconds (clang) per iteration.

Comment: This would be interesting to test that with multiple threads. A global lock might be really bad in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there will be a cost to check whether the object has been initialised. This would typically test an atomic Boolean variable, rather than lock a mutex.

Comment: @user3175411 The exact mechanism used by implementations to ensure threadsafe initialization of function-local statics is not specified by the standard (presumably to allow for implementation freedom). A pure spinlock would be a poor choice for most implementations, but it's not totally out of the question.

Comment: @user3175411 Memory barriers are required, too. This ensures, that the effect of the initialization of the vector will be _visible_ in the current thread.