# Function local static variables: pros/cons from performance point of view

Tags: c++, performance, static, local

What are the pros/cons of function local static variables **purely from performance point of view**?

Here is an example:

```cpp
// version 1
void func(/*some arguments here*/)
{
 int64_t x;
 int32_t y = 0;
 void * p = 0;
 // do something here
}

// version 2
void func(/*some arguments here*/)
{
 static int64_t x;
 static int32_t y; y = 0;
 static void * p; p = 0;
 // do something here
}
```

Which version will be faster? Will it always be faster? In what situation one might shoot oneself in the foot by using static local variables for performance?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: *Which version will be faster?* -- Please measure.  Second, static variables as of C++ 11 are required to have thread-safe initialization, as opposed to local variables which are always thread safe.  Thus there will more than likely be a performance hit with `static`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488559/is-there-a-penalty-for-using-static-variables-in-c11

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Thank you! So, the answer is "it depends, but most likely the performance will suffer".

Comment: One very large reason to avoid function local static variables is it makes the function non-thread safe if you write to them unless you explicitly add synchronization yourself which will even add more of a performance hit.  You could use `thread_local` but that still incurs a hit.  Avoid them unless the problem specifically calls for it.

Comment: There might be an exception to the rule: 1. You are definitely in a single-threaded environment and won't ever get multi-threaded. 2. Constructing the object in question is expensive (maybe allocation of large chunks of memory involved), but simply resetting the object is cheap. But if you ever break the promise of being single-threaded, you'll be in trouble! So this might be a consideration *only* if you discover after *profiling(!)* that you have a real bottleneck exactly at this location, anything else would be premature optimisation.

Comment: you can try to make some instruction in loop en measure. The experience can change by changing machine, compiler, OS etc..

Comment: **C or C++**? Please pick one per question, since the two are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad to be generally answered. However, I would just share my experience with the development of some real-world applications. As pointed out by @Aconcagua in comments, if an auxiliary (not-returned) local object is expensive to initialize or use, making it `static` and reusing it might result in significant speedup. This happens in our cases especially with auxiliary local vectors, where reusing avoids heap allocations. Compare

```
void f() {
  std::vector<...> v;
  ...  // at least one allocation required in each call when inserting elements
}
```

with

```
void f() {
  static std::vector<...> v;
  v.clear();
  ...  // no allocation required if elements fit into capacity
}
```

The same applies to (non-small) strings. Of course, if very large vectors/strings may be created this way, one should be aware that this approach may considerably increase process RSS (amount of memory mapped to RAM).

In multi-threaded applications, we just use `thread_local` instead of `static`.

---

On the other hand, for small objects, basically of fundamental types (such as integers or pointers in your exemplary code), I would dare to say that making them `static` may result in more memory accesses. With *non-static variables*, they will be more likely *mapped to registers* only. With *static variables*, their values must be preserved between function calls, which will much likely result in their *storage in memory*.

Comment: What’s “program RSS”?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Changed _program_ to _process_.

Comment: OK, what’s “process RSS”? It’s just not a common abbreviation unless you work specifically close to the operating system.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sorry, thought you were pointing to the incorrect usage of _program_. _Resident set size_ — the amount of memory mapped to RAM. I added a note into the answer.