# Performance concerns of using static variables inside display function in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, static

I'm learning OpenGL 4 and am reading an ebook *Computer Graphics Programming in OpenGL with C++ Second Edition*. They explain that it is very important in our display function, where drawing operations are handled, that we avoid instantiating objects or declaring variables to maximize performance and minimize overhead. Which is why up until that point they'd been globally declaring variables used in the display function as a means to avoid any memory allocation locally.

I've been instead opting to use `static` variables in the display function like so:

```
void display(GLFWwindow* window, double currentTime) {

    static float cameraX = 0.0f, cameraY = 0.0f, cameraZ = 20.0f; // <-- statically assigned 

    glm::mat4 mMat, vMat, pMat, mvMat;

    int width, height;

    std::stack<glm::mat4> mvStack;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    float aspect = static_cast<float>(width) / static_cast<float>(height);

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(renderingProgram);

    GLuint mvLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
    GLuint pLoc = glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "p_matrix");

    pMat = glm::perspective(1.0472f, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

    vMat = glm::translate( glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(-cameraX, -cameraY, -cameraZ) );
    mvStack.push(vMat);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(pLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(pMat));

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), static_cast<float>(currentTime), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvStack.top()));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18);

    mvStack.pop();

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),
        glm::vec3(
            sin(static_cast<float>(currentTime)) * 4.0f,
            0.0f,
            cos(static_cast<float>(currentTime)) * 4.0f
        ));

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), static_cast<float>(currentTime), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvStack.top()));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    mvStack.pop();

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),
        glm::vec3(
            0.0f,
            sin(static_cast<float>(currentTime) * 0.5) * 2.0f,
            cos(static_cast<float>(currentTime) * 0.5) * 2.0f
        ));

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), static_cast<float>(currentTime), glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    mvStack.push(mvStack.top());
    mvStack.top() *= glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.25f));

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvStack.top()));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    mvStack.pop(); mvStack.pop(); mvStack.pop(); mvStack.pop();
}
```

`static` variables are initialized once in a function and maintain their original value throughout the scope of that function and go out of scope with that function. In my mind since it's only allocated once, assigned to once and maintains the same value and address in memory then there shouldn't be much of a performance concern except during the very first call of the function when the variable is actually instantiated.

Any performance concerns to keep in mind? Would global variables be a better alternative in terms of performance?

Comment: You define the `camera` variables, initialize them to a value, and then use their negative values. But you never change the variables. You might as well use constants. Perhaps `constexpr float cameraX = 0.0f;`? Then the compiler will be able to replace the variables with the actual value at compile-time, which means there won't be anything extra at runtime.

Comment: As for any performance effect of using static local variables as compared to global (possibly static) variables, there likely won't be anything that you will notice or be able to measure. In fact even with your current code where the variables aren't constants, the compiler might treat them as such anyway. Look at the generated code (built with optimizations enabled of course).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My apologies, I'm only now realizing I worded my question poorly as it implies I have no intention of changing `camera` values in the future. I will likely be adding input handling soon to move the camera. However, I will definitely keep your suggestions in mind with other variables I plan to add. Thank you.

Comment: Well that changes things somewhat... :) Then you probably don't want static variables either actually, as you should separate input from rendering. Perhaps a camera class and  pass or keep a reference to it in the rendering class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question can be simplied down to this one [Is there a penalty for using static variables in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488559/is-there-a-penalty-for-using-static-variables-in-c11), and it seems that the answer is "yes, but mildly"

The second answer posits an explanation to this:

> Yes, there will be a cost to check whether the object has been
> initialised. This would typically test an atomic Boolean variable,
> rather than lock a mutex. [@Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour)

I believe it is better to examine the linked question and the top answer, they are golden

Comment: Indeed, very good information. For now I'll proceed with using `static` variables. If performance becomes an issue later I may revisit this topic but it seems like a very minor implementation detail in the context of other things that could be done to improve performance. Much appreciated.